# Permission denied when sorting in-place and overwriting

Tags: linux, sort

I am trying to sort the following file in-place and overwrite the original file using sort -o command, but seems the sortation is not successful. It is totally fine when I save the sorted result into a new file. Is there any way to resolve this?

input.txt

```
FBgn0029994  -1.25          -0.27
FBgn0037191  -1.05          0.78
FBgn0036810  2.08           1.34
FBgn0033320  1.15           0.45

sort -o -t$'\t' -k2 input.txt input.txt
```

output

```
FBgn0037191 -1.05   0.78
FBgn0033320 1.15    0.45
FBgn0029994 -1.25   -0.27
FBgn0036810 2.08    1.34
```

Comment: What is the result of `ls -l file`?

Comment: Did you literally get `permission denied` or is the title only your *interpretation*? Did you really get the posted output from the posted command? or any output at all? My point is `-o` takes a filename as its option-argument and in your case the filename is `-t$'\t'` (after the shell expands it, if ever). I would say you now have a file with the name starting with `-t` and the result from sorting 2x`input.txt` is there. But your `sort` command, while writing to the file, would print neither `permission denied` nor anything. So maybe the command was different? There's something fishy here.